# Type Observable<Response> is not assignable to type Observable<List<Todo>>

Tags: angular, typescript, system.reactive, rxjs

I'm trying to build an application loosely following [this application](https://github.com/jhades/angular2-rxjs-observable-data-services/blob/master/src/TodoBackendService.ts) but I am getting a TypeScript error and I'd like an explanation of what is wrong. To the best of my knowledge I'm doing what I'm supposed to.

Here's the code I've written thus far:

```
import {Injectable,Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Headers,URLSearchParams, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {List, Record} from 'immutable';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";


const TodoRecord = Record({
    id: 0,
    description: "",
    completed: false
});

export class Todo extends TodoRecord {

    id:number;
    description:string;
    completed: boolean;

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

}

@Injectable()

export class TodoBackendService {
    constructor(private http: Http){
        this.http = http;
    }

    getAllTodos(){
        return this.http.get("/todo");
    }

    saveTodo(newTodo: Todo): Observable<List<Todo>> {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json; chartset=utf-8");

        return this.http.post("/todo", JSON.stringify(newTodo.toJS()),{headers}).share();
    }
}
```

This is the line of code Visual Studio Code identifies as an error:

```
 return this.http.post("/todo", JSON.stringify(newTodo.toJS()),{headers}).share();
```

And this is the error message I get in VS Code:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, the message says it all. An http post returns an Observable<Response>, not an Observable<List<Todo>>. You need to use map() to create a List<Todo> from the returned response.

Comment: There you go. Write an answer and I'll accept it as the correct answer. Get yourself some SO points!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message says it all. An http post returns an `Observable<Response>`, not an `Observable<List<Todo>>`.

You need to use `map()` to create a `List<Todo>` from the returned response.

Answer (score 4):

This is how to use map. Assuming that response.json() returns an array of ToDo models.

```
saveTodo(newTodo: Todo): Observable<List<Todo>> {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json; chartset=utf-8");

    return this.http.post("/todo", JSON.stringify(newTodo.toJS()),{headers})
        .map((response: Response) => (<ToDo[]>response.json())).share();
}
```

Comment: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'.

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
saveTodo(newTodo: Todo) : Observable<any> {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        return this.http.post('/todo',JSON.stringify(newTodo.toJS()),{headers}).share();
    }
```